# How was I able to close a question after running out of votes?

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, voting, closed-questions

Time is now 9:10am (local) and I ran out of votes at [4:33am](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8002614#8002614).

However this question created at 8:33am https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15158884/undefined-variable-where-in-joomla-libraries-joomla-database-database-mysql-php shows me as closing it.

The thing is the question was *closed* AND *created* hours after I ran out of votes. I still can't vote on anything as I have 9 more hours to get votes again. How was I able to close that question?

Comment: Did you run out of *review votes* or out of *close votes*?

Comment: @MartijnPieters close votes, and I would not be able to review close-votes as it is greyed out on the review page as I am out of them.

Comment: Do you at least remember trying to VTC? Or are you saying your name just randomly appeared there?

Comment: Has one of the questions you closed been deleted? Can you count the number of close votes in your votes tab for today?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards 39 close votes that occurred within less than 24hours. I assume some of the questions have been deleted since then, however I am still unable to cast votes for approx 8 hours.

Comment: @bfavaretto honestly, I don't remember if I tried or not. It's second nature to me to click the close button on such a question, but I get the error message about no votes if I do. Clicking it should still not have allowed me to vote as I had run out well before then, as the question was created/closed within my vote lockout period. I don't think it just randomly appeared, it somehow had accepted a vote.

Comment: @crypticツ You have 50 close votes per day, but can only review 40 posts from the close votes queue (not counting skipped posts).

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm not understanding how running out of those 50 daily votes would still allow me to vote again within the lockout period. If I run out of those 50 votes I can't even review close-votes as the option is grayed out on the review page.

Comment: It wouldn't. But In your reply to ben, you wrote of 39 close votes showing in the last 24 hours, so it could be that you didn't actually run out of close votes, but only spent your daily queue-allowance. Can you just click on the `close` link of a random question to see what the popup says?

Comment: @DanielFischer Clicking a close vote link will error saying I am out of votes and I need to wait x hours. `You've reached the maximum of 50 Closure votes per day; come back in 8 hours`

Comment: Okay. Does the close vote on that particular question appear in your close votes list? [Ought to.] So either you were mistaken and did not actually run out of close votes when you thought you did, or you gained an additional close vote during the day for some impenetrable reason. (Or the system hiccoughed and it wasn't actually your close vote, but that seems very unlikely.)

Comment: @DanielFischer it is listed as the last close vote, and it occurred ~4 hours after the 2nd to last close vote. I know I ran out of votes because I got the error when I tried to close another and my votes showed as 0. I then just posted cv-pls links in the chat instead as I could not close anymore. Is there an admin who can look into this and tell me if I'm crazy or not? O_o

Comment: It happened again. This time I was paying attention and noticed my available votes had changed from 0 to 1 and I got an extra vote again. Still don't know why it is happening. It only seems to be just 1 vote more.

Comment: Would be nice if [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222) would get updated once you have an answer.

Comment: Third time's a charm. Happened again today, a mysterious extra vote appeared hours after I had run out of votes.